# Ordenar columna manteniendo nombres de filas

Tags: r

¿Cómo hago para ordenar un df conservando el nombre de las filas?
Pongo un ejemplo de lo que me ocurre.

A los datos iris le añado algunos valores desconocidos.

```
for (i in 1:4) 
  iris[sample(200, 50), i] <- NA
```

A continuación calculo el porcentaje de desconocidos por columna.

```
datos <- data.frame(Porcentaje=sapply(iris, function(x) {mean(is.na(x))*100}))
```

```
             Porcentaje
Sepal.Length   57.28643
Sepal.Width    59.29648
Petal.Length   54.77387
Petal.Width    53.26633
Species        24.62312
```

Lo ordeno de mayor a menor.

```
datos[order(datos, decreasing =T),]
```

Me sale

```
[1] 59.29648 57.28643 54.77387 53.26633 24.62312
```

Cuando lo que busco es que me devuelva:

```
 
             Porcentaje
Sepal.Width    59.29648
Sepal.Length   57.28643
Petal.Length   54.77387
Petal.Width    53.26633
Species        24.62312
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es un tema habitual y ciertamente discutible de R, pero es funcionalidad básica y es fundamental tenerlo bien claro, por que confunde y es una fuente de errores muy clásica. La situación se da con cualquier operación sobre un objeto que pueda asimilarse como un objeto más primitivo, por eliminación de dimensiones. En este caso, un `data.frame` de una única columna se convierte implícitamente en un vector. En tu caso, no es que pierdes los nombres de las filas, lo que ocurre es que el resultado dejó de ser un `data.frame` y en ese proceso se pierden los `rownames`.

La solución a esto, es usar el parámetro `drop = FALSE` con lo cual le decimos a R que respete el mismo tipo de dato de origen para el resultado final, aún si el mismo pudiera transformarse en un tipo más primitivo.

```
datos[order(datos, decreasing =T), ,drop = FALSE]

             Porcentaje
Sepal.Width        46.5
Sepal.Length       46.0
Petal.Length       45.0
Petal.Width        43.5
Species            25.0
```

El libro de Patrick Burns [The R inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) tiene una buena documentación de esto en "8.1.45 drop data frames" y en "8.1.46 losing row names"

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo no mantener los nombres de fila *fuera* del data.frame porque, como viste, es fácil perderlos. Aquí te presento una solución que utiliza funciones del `tidyverse` para obtener lo que buscas. El output es un tipo especial de data.frame llamado *tibble*. Uso el pipe (`%>%`) para encadenar los pasos.

### Respuesta

```r
library(tidyverse)

iris %>% 
  summarise(across(.fns = ~mean(is.na(.x))*100)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(), 
               names_to = "Variable", 
               values_to = "Porcentaje") %>% 
  arrange(desc(Porcentaje))
```

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  Variable     Porcentaje
  <chr>             <dbl>
1 Petal.Length       61  
2 Petal.Width        59  
3 Sepal.Length       58.5
4 Sepal.Width        56.5
5 Species            25
```

### Paso a paso

#### iris local

Fue necesario crear una copia local de `iris` para mantener los `NA`s.

```
iris <- iris

for (i in 1:4) {iris[sample(200, 50), i] <- NA}
```

#### Cargando los paquetes

El meta-paquete `tidyverse` carga los paquetes `dplyr` y `tidyr` necesarios para la solución. Carga también otros paquetes más pero no vienen al caso ni interfieren.

```r
library(tidyverse)
```

#### Función a través de columnas

El siguiente paso es obtener la proporción de `NA`s por cada columna. Usamos `summarise()` combinado con `across()` para ello. Le estamos pidiendo que aplique una función anónima a todas las columnas.

```r
iris %>% 
  summarise(across(.fns = ~mean(is.na(.x))*100))
```

El resultado es:

```
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1         58.5        56.5           61          59      25
```

#### Pivotear

Lo siguiente es convertir los nombres de columna en nombres de fila. Para ello usamos la función `pivot_longer()`. En este caso debemos explícitamente pedirle que agarre todas las columnas.

```r
iris %>% 
  summarise(across(.fns = ~mean(is.na(.x))*100)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(), 
               names_to = "Variable", 
               values_to = "Porcentaje")
```

Obtenemos:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  Variable     Porcentaje
  <chr>             <dbl>
1 Sepal.Length       58.5
2 Sepal.Width        56.5
3 Petal.Length       61  
4 Petal.Width        59  
5 Species            25
```

#### Ordenar por valor

El último paso es ordenar de forma descendente según el valor de *Porcentaje*. Para ello, usamos `arrange()` y `desc()`.

```r
iris %>% 
  summarise(across(.fns = ~mean(is.na(.x))*100)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(), 
               names_to = "Variable", 
               values_to = "Porcentaje") %>% 
  arrange(desc(Porcentaje))
```

Lo que nos da el resultado que ves al inicio.